# mapserver Unable to open .map file

Tags: php, html, qgis, mapserver

```
Warning: [MapServer Error]: msLoadMap(): in D:\ms4w\apps\seri\htdocss\common\wrapper\map_session.php on line 215

Warning: Failed to open map file D:\ms4w\apps\seri\htdocs/../map/bandi.map in D:\ms4w\apps\seri\htdocss\common\wrapper\map_session.php on line 215

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\ms4w\apps\seri\htdocss\widgets\KeyMapDHTML\KeyMapDHTML.widget.php on line 115

Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on a non-object in D:\ms4w\apps\seri\htdocss\widgets\KeyMapDHTML\KeyMapDHTML.widget.php on line 115
```

Comment: You copied and pasted an error message as your question. What is your question? Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: This also looks like it might be better with a php tag than a Python tag currently.

Comment: Please specify your problem in your question. It's not enough to just post logs.

Answer (score 1):

(1)  make sure your bandi.map exists in the path D:\ms4w\apps\seri\map/bandi.map because that's where php Mapscript is looking for your mapfile.

(2) if answer to point (1) is YES, than double check that syntax of you mapfile does not caus problems, this can be done by going to your browser and setting the URL to `http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=D:\ms4w\apps\seri\map\bandi.map` .... check out the message it returns in your browser window.